# Stone-Weierstrass Theorem (Rudin)

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, inequality

I've been reading the proof of the Stone-Weierstrass Theorem in Rudin and I'm stuck on this inequality.

$$\sqrt{n}(1-\delta^2)^n<\varepsilon \text{ for } n\geq N  \text{ where } 0<\delta\leq1$$

Why is this true?

I can't find the solution by searching here and I've tried looking at the other Stone-Weierstrass questions.

Comment: It's certainly not true if $\delta =0.$ But basically it just boils down to $\sqrt n a^n \to 0$ if $0\le a <1.$ Remember, exponential decay always wins vs polynomial growth, so surely it beats $\sqrt n.$

Comment: Yes it should've said $\delta>0$. With regards to your comment I seem to have forgotten this fact, would you remind me how to show this?

Comment: It's right there in Rudin in the earlier chapters.

Comment: In Theorem 3.20 it says

$ \lim_{n\to\infty}(n)^{1/n} =1 $ but doesn't mention $lim_{n\to\infty }\sqrt{n}$. But maybe you meant another Theorem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement is equivalent to $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt{n(1-\delta^2)^{2n}} = 0$. Since $0 \le 1 - \delta^2 < 1$, put $\dfrac{1}{1+a} = \left(1- \delta^2\right)^2 \implies a >0\implies 0 \le n(1-\delta^2)^{2n} = \dfrac{n}{(1+a)^n}< \dfrac{n}{1+na+\dfrac{a^2n^2}{2}}< \dfrac{2}{a^2n}$. By squeeze theorem $n(1-\delta^2)^{2n} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$, and the result follows.

Comment: Very nice! I was thinking it might even be possible to apply the result of Theorem 3.20 d): for $p > 0 $ and $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$, then 

$$lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^\alpha}{(1+p)^n}=0 $$

directly since $\sqrt{n(1-\delta^2)^{2n}}\leq n(1-\delta^2)^{2n}$. Given that the expression is always positive.